# Allow one announcement during commitment phase

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, commitment-phase

I'd like to announce a [chat room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200/physics) for the [Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics?referrer=Ho2q28uHijgN5QfMOt5KEg2) proposal, but since comments can no longer be posted at the definition-phase tab (plus it would not be prominent), I'd like to announce this room directly on the commitment site.

If you find this to be too abusable, I softened it down to [Autmatically create one chat room for each proposal when it's in commitment-phase](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62500/autmatically-create-one-chat-room-for-each-proposal-when-its-in-commitment-phase).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comments and discussions are now possible during commitment, plus:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/area-51-gets-organized-lets-talk/