# Automatically create one chat room for each proposal when it's in commitment-phase

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, chat, commitment-phase

And let's have a link to it directly on the commitment-phase tab.

(this is a soft version of [Allow one announcement during commitment phase](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62499/allow-one-announcement-during-commitment-phase), probably less abusable)

Comment: I second this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56578/sending-e-mail-to-people-committed-to-a-proposal/61959#61959

Comment: @Ralph Rickenbach: I first thought you meant to support the email feature-request itself, but in that case: `you beat me to it` :p

Comment: it's good to have it as a question though, as the answer obviously did not get the visibility intended.

Comment: Interesting - in particular, though - the current chat *beta* will shortly be site-specific. That almost seems more like a chat.area51 - will ping past Robert.

Comment: Proposals in commitment phase can have chat rooms? I never knew that. A great tool to promote proposals, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> comments and discussions are now possible during commitment, plus:
>
> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/area-51-gets-organized-lets-talk/
> -- Jeff Atwood♦

[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62499/allow-one-announcement-during-commitment-phase/83706#83706)

So you can create a chat room now and then announce it at the proposal.

Comment: how can you create a chat room?

Comment: @Wikis go to http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/ and on the bottom choose `Create a new room`. Then leave a comment or discussion at the area 51 proposal to link to it

Comment: thanks: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/wikis-and-wikipedia-chat-room-open