# Allow site proposers to post an admin message during commitment phase

Tags: discussion, status-completed, area-51, commitment-phase, announcements

So, Jeff and Robert left admin messages at [Developer Testing : Unit Testing and more…](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8494/developer-testing-unit-testing-and-more) and [Electronics and Robotics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2651/electronics-and-robotics):

[image: announcing]

So, technically the [feature-request] [Allow one announcement during commitment phase](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62499/146482) is possible. Why not allow a proposal's author to do the same?

For example I'd like to hear the opinions of those committed to [Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics?referrer=Ho2q28uHijgN5QfMOt5KEg2) on [Combine the many proposals for a science Stack Exchange into one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65674/146482), or announce a [chat-room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62500/146482)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> comments and discussions are now
> possible during commitment, plus:
>
> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/area-51-gets-organized-lets-talk/
>
> -- Jeff Atwood♦

[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62499/allow-one-announcement-during-commitment-phase/83706#83706)